# Product Prices index process unknown error

Tags: ce-1.9.2.0, indexer

I am trying to run the indexer for product prices but it keeps erroring out (See Below). My catalog has approx 25,000 simple products and no attributes assigned to them. There are custom attributes created for the whole installation but they're not being used on the products at the moment.
I have increased the MySQL wait timeout, the packet size is already set very high.

Another thing I noticed was the VAR folder doesnt have a locks folder or any lock files.

I am running Community Version 1.9.2.0.

Any help would be appreciated as I have run out of ideas! Many Thanks.

```
    Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(72): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock/Storage/Db.php(84): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->releaseLock('mysite_magedb...')
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(208): Mage_Index_Model_Lock_Storage_Db->releaseLock('index_process_2')
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(181): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->_releaseLockDb('index_process_2')
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(469): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->releaseLock('index_process_2', NULL)
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(223): Mage_Index_Model_Process->unlock()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was: SELECT RELEASE_LOCK(?);' in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(72): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock/Storage/Db.php(84): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->releaseLock('mysite_magedb...')
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(208): Mage_Index_Model_Lock_Storage_Db->releaseLock('index_process_2')
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(181): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->_releaseLockDb('index_process_2')
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(469): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->releaseLock('index_process_2', NULL)
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(223): Mage_Index_Model_Process->unlock()
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(72):  in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: You mean `var/locks/` is empty not just `var/` correct? Also, I noticed the Query the deadlock was on is a SQL `RELEASE_LOCK` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

Comment: https://github.com/SchumacherFM/Magento-FastIndexer

Comment: Magento doesnt create a locks folder within var. Permissions etc are set correctly. I was thinking it may have been a locks issue but there are no locks to remove as the folder/files are not created.

Comment: I've never come across RELEASE_LOCK before, is it a DB thing?